# Change label's text with using property

Tags: ado.net, foreach, label

I am working on my C# ADO.NET app. I have connected my SQL Server database with C# app, and I can perform simple CRUD operations. I want to make that my app open my reminder form when someone in my database have birthday, so I made my query and all persons who have birthday on today's day are in my query, and with using property from my reminder form I change label's text with name and surname of person who have birthday. Now I just dont know how to change next label's text when more than one person have birthday in my query... I dont know how to get next element in my foreach loop...

Here is my code:

```
    Form2 forma = new Form2();
    TBirthDayEntities today_born = new TBirthDayEntities();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private Boolean provjera_rodj()
    {
        Boolean flag = false;
        int cnt = 0;


        IQueryable<TBD> query;
        using (var data = new TBirthDayEntities())
        {
            query = (from x in data.TBD
                     where x.BirthDay.Day == System.DateTime.Now.Day && x.BirthDay.Month == System.DateTime.Now.Month
                     select x);

            foreach (var x in query)
            {
                    today_born.TBD.Add(x);
                    cnt += 1;
                    flag = true;


            }
        }





        switch (cnt)
        {
            case 1:
                {
                    foreach (var x in today_born.TBD)
                    {
                                forma.p_label2 = x.FName + " " + x.LName;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    foreach (var x in today_born.TBD)
                    {
                        forma.p_label2 = x.FName + x.LName;
                        forma.p_label3 = x.FName + x.LName; //wrong
                    }
                    break;
                }

        }



        return flag;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Boolean flag = provjera_rodj();
        if (flag == true)
        {
            forma.Show();
            timer1.Stop();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    switch (cnt)
    {
        case 1:
        case 2:
            {
                var lstLabel = new List<Label>()
                {
                    forma.p_label2
                    , forma.p_label3
                };
                for(int i = 0; i < today_born.TBD.Count; i++)
                {
                    var x in today_born.TBD[i];

                    lstLabel[x].Text = x.FName + x.LName;
                }
                break;
            }

    }
```

EDIT:

```
    switch (cnt)
    {
        case 1:
        case 2:
            {
                var lstLabel = new List<Action<string>>()
                {
                    new Action<string>(s =>forma.p_label2 = s)
                    , new Action<string>(s =>forma.p_label3 = s)
                };
                for(int i = 0; i < today_born.TBD.Count; i++)
                {
                    var x = today_born.TBD[i];

                    lstLabel[x](x.FName + x.LName);
                }
                break;
            }

    }
```

Comment: First thanks for answering my question.
Ofc p_label2 and p_label3 are not labels, I wrote in my question that I'm using label properties to change their text and p_label2 and p_label3 are properties for changing labels text. Still I have problem with list type, what should I put in those brackets ?

Comment: It doesnt work. U can't use this line:
   `var x in today_born.TBD[i];` without `using` and I have error on this line ` lstLabel[x](x.FName + x.LName);`

Comment: "in" should be "=" sorry for the (obvious) typo. What's the other error you get?

Comment: In this line: `var x = today_born.TBD[i];` I have error

Error 1 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<BirthDayApp.TBD>' C:\Users\Mensur i Mahir\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BirthDayApp\BirthDayApp\Form1.cs 67 37 BirthDayApp